# Earning money in Tiny Tower through stocks?

Tags: tiny-tower

So I've been playing the game for a while, but every time I fill up stocks in the stores, they stay exactly the same whether I'm playing it or not. The only money I get is by the quick sell option, shipping people to random floors, and filling up stocks in new stores. How can I actually make money by not really doing anything like most people?

Comment: Perhaps your game is bugged?  If the store is stocked, people will eventually buy that stock in your store.  You shouldn't have to do anything else.  (Unless you're doing something silly like moving your employees around and not keeping them at any particular store, but even then I think the stores may still sell stock without any employees there.)

Comment: This happened to my game when I'd been doing the 'set the time forward/back in iOS' trick. All I did to remedy it was to completely quit out of TT (double click home, remove TT from the running programs) and reboot my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

I play TT Now and again and the only thing I can think is that your staff don't have enough skill. Try to have people in their "dream job" or at least the correct field ( same colour ) . Not only does this reduce the cost of stock ( from memory, I don't have it installed right now ) by a max of 27% (9 for each staff that is 9 in that colour) but I believe it also increases their selling rate.